# Python with requests.post hangs script if connection drops

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have a problem in Python3 with requests.post. If my 4g connection drops immediately after the script accesses the request.post the script gets stuck and only comes back after Ctrl + C. It seems that he gets lost trying to understand why the connection has fallen and does nothing else. It should go immediately to the except, but gets stuck and just goes to the except after I hit Ctrl + C and unlock it. Has anyone ever had this problem?

```
try:
  T = requests.post(...)
  "my connection drops"
  "the script hangs and does nothing else"
  if T.ok:
   print('sucesss')

  else:
   print('error')

except:
 print('except')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it keeps retrying until the POST request is completed. This can be solved using a timeout

Try using this code

```
try:
  T = requests.post(yoururlandquery, timeout=20)
except requests.Timeout:
  print('oops, looks like the 4g dropped')
```